# In JS, why doesn't logging the argument in catch(err) show the full response object?

Tags: javascript, object, error-handling, try-catch

If I print the following

```
 catch (exception) {
      console.log(`Just exception (type: ${typeof(exception)}): `, exception)
      console.log(`Full response (type: ${typeof(exception.response)}): `, exception.response)
```

I get this result in the browser´s console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oql9Z.png)

I normally print in the console responses to see their structure and discover how to navigate them, but when I log the argument of catch, the response does not display its full structure, despite being an object, forcing me to use err.response to see the actual object.

Why does this happen? Is there any way of knowing if responses have a hidden structure that is not displayed when printing them?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few special sorts of object expressions that, when logged, do not display the JavaScript properties and values like normal, but something else. Some things that have this behavior include:

- DOM elements
- Functions
- Errors

In these cases and others, some environments log something custom instead of the object structure.

```js
console.log(document.body);
console.log(() => 'foo');
console.log(new Error('err!'));
```

[image]

To view the object structure, use `console.dir` instead of `console.log`.

Comment: Thanks! Had no idea about console.dir.